# Can Visual Studio 2017 Run .Net Core 1.x Projects without migration to 2.0?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I just installed VS2017 v15.7, but am having trouble running a Core 1.x Project with it. It keeps asking for 1.0.4. Does this version of VS17 support running 1.x projects without migration to 2.x ? If it can run 1.x what am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, VS 2017 will run/build .NET Core 1.x versions. You may need to install the specific SDK for your version however.

A list of versions can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/core/tree/master/release-notes/download-archives)

Comment: Thanks. You were bang-on. Not sure if this is against the policies, in which case i apologize, but i asked another question and i will really really appreciate the help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50548137/how-to-use-an-mdf-database-file-with-a-visual-studio-project-without-connection